# Find the area enclosed by $r = 1 + \sin\theta$ and $r = 1 - \sin\theta$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Find the area enclosed by $r = 1 + \sin\theta$ and $r = 1 - \sin\theta$

So, the curves are given by the following parametrizations:

$$ f_1(\theta) = ((1 + \sin \theta) \cos \theta,(1 + \sin \theta) \sin \theta)$$
$$  f_2(\theta) = ((1 - \sin \theta) \cos \theta,(1 - \sin \theta) \sin \theta)$$

It looks logical that I have to find the intersections.

How can I find the integral enclosed by the curves?

Comment: There is no need to go into parametric. Have you heard of the integral 0.5r^2?

Comment: @imranfat That was in the question :) I have never heard of that integral...

Comment: By symmetry, the integral is zero...

Comment: In this question, the area is not zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use symmetry and multiply $0.5\int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\sin\theta)^2 d\theta$ by $4$. When you expand, you get three integrals that are all standard.That I want you to try. You should find $\frac{3\pi-8}{2}$ (And not zero!)

Comment: I learnt about double integrals. Think that is the way I should do it. How do you get this single integral?

Comment: I found out the double integral that leads to this integral. $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{1-sin(\theta)} rdrd\theta$ and I think I understand why that is the integral I need. Why is the area nonzero? Thank you!

Comment: You can also do this problem with a double integral. The area is not zero because clearly there is area between the curves. A polar curve "generates" area differently than a function y=f(x), where area under the x-axis is considered negative and thus where a net area can be assumed zero. Not here. If you look at the derivation of my formula through the use of a Riemann Sum, it will become crystal clear. Try to get my answer with your double integral. It's a good exercise